# javascript Validation Help a total newbie

Tags: javascript

I Cannot get the javascript to work! I need the `Password` and `Re-Type Password` fields, validate that both have values and that the user has entered the same password in both fields (i.e. password match) validate the password field must be more than 8 characters.I dont want to use the alert function instead, highlight the uncompleted fields with red background and a text message next to each uncompleted field (in red color) with the error message.

I have spent 3 days doing this!! any help appreciated.`

```js
 function validate() {
   var fn =
     document.getElementById("FName");
   if (fn.value == "") {

     {
       document.getElementById("FName").style.borderColor = "red";
       return false;

     }
     return true;
   }

   function validate() {
     var sn =
       document.getElementById("SName");
     if (sn.value == "") {
       document.getElementById("SName").style.borderColor = "red";
       return false;

     }
     return true;
   }

   function validate() {
     var un =
       document.getElementById("UName");
     if (un.value == "") {
       document.getElementById("UName").style.borderColor = "red";
       return false;

     }
     return true;
   }

   function checkPass() {
     var pass = document.getElementById('pass');
     var c_pass = document.getElementById(' c_pass')
     var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
     var goodColor = "#66cc66";
     var badColor = "#ff6666";

     if (pass.value == c_pass.value) {

       c_pass.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
       message.style.color = goodColor;
       message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!"
     } else {

       c_pass.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
       message.style.color = badColor;
       message.innerHTML = "Passwords Do Not Match!"

     }
     return true;
   }
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="Linkpage.html" id="myForm" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate())">
  </form>
  <br>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="2"><span style="font-size:50px; color:blue;">Registration form</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="2">Welcome to our website
        <br>please fill in <span style=" color:red;">all</span>
        <b><ins>fields</ins></b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>
        <input autofocus="" id="FName" placeholder="Enter First name " type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td>
        <input id="SName" placeholder="Enter Last name " type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Username</td>
      <td>
        <input id="UName" placeholder="Enter username " type "text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>
        <input id="Age" placeholder="Enter age" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td>
        <input id="pass" placeholder="Enter password " type="password">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Confirm Password</td>
      <td>
        <input name="confirm password" id="c_pass" placeholder="Re-type your           password " type="password" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;">
        <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Gender</td>
      <td>
        <input name="mGender" type="radio" value="Male">Male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="fGender" type="radio" value="Female">Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Available</td>
      <td>
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Course</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="Mobile App">
            Mobile App
          </option>
          <option value="Cloud">
            Cloud
          </option>
          <option value="Software Development">
            Software Development
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Comments">Comments</td>
      <td>
        <br>
        <textarea cols="30" name="Comments" placeholder="Type your comments here." rows="6"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="4" align="center">
        <input name="submit" onclick="return validate()" type="submit" value="Register" align="center" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: So.... exactly which part is not working correctly?

Comment: none of the javascript the background colours matching passwords or alerts wont show!

Comment: Takendark All i have managed to do is not let the form submit!

Comment: Errrr, you have **three** functions named `validate`, why?

Comment: not sure!!! This is my first time coding u_mulder

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a lot of bugs in your code and this is normal as a beginner its great to see you trying. So what I have done is took a look at your javascript. I am not going to re-write you whole script but I have commented out the part you should take a look at and try and comment one part at a time to see where you problem is. But I did get your match password working for you by commenting out your other stuff. Just try this for now. Then remove comments line by line until it stops working again. This will tell you how to find the other error's in your script.

```
<script>
    function checkPass(){
       var passValue = document.getElementById('pass').value;
       var c_passValue = document.getElementById('c_pass').value;
       var c_passID = document.getElementById('c_pass');
       var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
       var goodColor = "#66cc66";
       var badColor = "#ff6666";


       if(passValue == c_passValue) {

          c_passID.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
          message.style.color = goodColor;
          message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!";

       } else {

          c_passID.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
          message.style.color = badColor;
          message.innerHTML = "Passwords Do Not Match!";

       }

    }

</script>
```

Okay so the issue was that you were attempting to change the color of the value of the c_pass and not the id itself. I renamed your variables to help you understand why it was breaking. Again this is only for the checkPass function. If you comment out all the other stuff and just use this script for now this will help you isolate the checkPass function and see that it works. I hope this helps.

Comment: I re-edited the script/answer to try and help you understand what was making the script break. Let me know if you can get this working and if you need any more help.

Comment: Hi Nothing is working now! passwords did with previous comment!!

Comment: can you update your code in the question and I can take a look at it.

Comment: have decided to use jquery is that a bad idea?

Comment: Not at all jquery makes things easier and quicker to do by cutting down the amount of code you need to write... jQuery is really just a JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here...

Get rid of the `table`, `tr` and `td`. You open a `form` and then you close it.  Add all of your `input` fields in the `form`.

Then don't add three functions all called validate.  Which one do you suppose is going to be called? 
Rather change them to

`function validateFname()`

`function validateSname()`

`function validateUname()`

then

Use `===` and `!===` instead of `==` and `!=`.

I think when you start clearing up your JavaScript and your HTML, things will start to make more sense.

Did you try to debug your code using Chrome's debugger or similar?

Comment: Hi this is homework and we were asked to put it into a table!

Answer (score 0):

Each time you write the validate() function, you're overwriting the previous instance of it.

I recommend instead of using the same function name 3 times, write 2 different functions - matches() and required(), each with a different purpose.

```
matches(field1, field2){
    return field1 == field2;
}

required(field){
    return field != false;
}
```

Then you can pass *into* those functions the various fields you're validating.

Comment: Hi Aaron I dont understand how to do that! I have only had one lesson in this! can you give me an example of where to put the above!